# Include additional highcharts source data in angular2 app

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using angular2-highcharts for a project and I am unable to create Solid Gauge charts as I require highcharts-more.js to be included within the project. How do I go about including this, if it is possible?

An example of this not in angular2 is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/). I need to be able to include information like this

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
```

I have the both highcharts and angular2-highcharts installed and within package.json.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo for solid-gauge in Angluar2 with `angular2-highcharts`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6EtK5kldXPLWs6v6Dk3w?p=preview

I have imported both required files: `highcharts-more` and `modules/solid-gauge` from same version as the one used by `angular2-highcharts` (BTW. this is a third party in relation to Highcharts). You can see that in `systemjs.config.js` file lines 18-19 and in `app/main.js` lines 4-8. In latter group of lines the additional files are initialized on Highcharts.

The demo I have posted is based on `angular2-highcharts` demo for [using Highcharts with modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#using-highchart-modules): http://plnkr.co/edit/4Eifda2IPpCjykONSQQJ?p=preview

Important parts of the code:

**app/main.js:**

```
...
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES, Highcharts } from 'angular2-highcharts'; 
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import HCSoldGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge';

HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
HCSoldGauge(Highcharts);
...
```

**systemjs.config.js:**

```
 ...
'angular2-highcharts':        'https://cdn.rawgit.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/0.1.0/dist',
'highcharts/highstock.src':   'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/v4.2.1/highstock.js',
'highcharts/highcharts-more': 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/v4.2.1/highcharts-more.js',
'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge': 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/v4.2.1/modules/solid-gauge.js'
...
```

Comment: This is cool. It seems it's broken however for the latest abgular2, and angular2-highcharts, could you publish an update?

Comment: @EMa I do not know where is a demo in plunker for the latest version, but based on [the new info on the angular2-highcharts npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#access-to-the-highcharts-static-members-and-modules) it's possible to get this working like in [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/wKWO1HQwX9o23g5v9ozW?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
    It's working. angular2-seed-ng2highcharts 

ref: https://github.com/AngularShowcase/angular2-seed-ng2-highcharts
    chart.html:
    -------------
    <div [ng2-highcharts]="chartGauge" class="graph" ></div>

    chart.component.ts:
    ------------------

    Add series option within the chart option.

    chartGauge = {
            chart: {
                        type: 'solidgauge'
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'ASUP'

                    },

                    pane: {
                        center: ['50%', '70%'],
                        size: '140%',
                        startAngle: -90,
                        endAngle: 90,
                        background: {
                            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                            innerRadius: '60%',
                            outerRadius: '100%',
                            shape: 'arc'
                        }
                    },


                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: true
                    },

                    // the value axis
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 200,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Speed'
                        }
                        stops: [
                            [0.5, '#FF5252'], // red*
                            [0.9, '#69F0AE'] // green

                        ],
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        minorTickInterval: null,
                        tickAmount: 1,
                        title: {
                            y: -40
                        },
                        labels: {
                            y: 15
                        }
                    },

                    plotOptions: {
                        solidgauge: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                y: 25,
                                borderWidth: 0,
                                useHTML: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    series: [{
                name: 'Speed',
                data: [80],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                        ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                           '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' km/h'
                }
            }]
      };
```